# Sending data to server and then refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to send some data to server, and deal with that data in server, and finally apply that data by refreshing the page.

I wrote my server-side script by node.js, and used http form to send the data.

But I don't know how to send the data while maintaing my original page.

Only methods I know is get/post and deal with it by app.get / app.post in node.js, like this.

```
app.get('/filtered.html',async function(req,res){
    let db = await getDBConnection();
    let rows = await db.all('select * from items');
    await db.close();

    var output=new Array();
    var id =  new Array();
    var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;

    if(query.productFilter=='All'||query.productFilter==''){
        for(let i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            output.push(rows[i]['product_image']);
            id.push(rows[i]['product_id']);
        }   
    }else{
        for(let i=0;i<rows.length;i++){        
            if(rows[i]['product_category']==query.productFilter){
                output.push(rows[i]['product_image']);
                id.push(rows[i]['product_id']);
            }
        }
    }
    
    var output_send = JSON.stringify(output);
    var id_send = JSON.stringify(id);

    res.render('index',{
        data: output_send,
        data2 : id_send
    });
});
```

So once I send the data by submit button and try to refresh the page, I'm still in the page such as .../product/:id/?result=xxxx... (original page = ..../product/:id )

Could you please teach me some measures to send data while maintaining original page? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to make an HTTP request using JavaScript on the client side?  For example, with the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API?

Comment: Yeah, but honestly I'm doing my assignment, it allows googling but does not allow using fetch API. that is the condition for this assignment.

Comment: If you can't make an HTTP request from the browser, how do you expect to "maintain the original page?"  Another option, I suppose, is _navigation_, perhaps to a URL with a query string, but that will load a new page.